# Is there a term to say yes to something without being committed to it?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, generic-term

I feel that this would be reeeally, really useful. A term that wraps up this sentence nicely would be swell:

```
'Yes, though as of during now till then if I think of a logically sound reason why
the thing I just agreed to is actually kinda dumb, I would like the option to not 
do/attend said thing at any time, without it looking irresponsible'.
```

Because if there's not a term to describe all that. Then there needs to be.

Comment: Maybe. But it would violate at least three of the Gricean maxims.

Comment: Don't care needs to happen.

Comment: You know what, I got it; 'yes but without obligation'.

Comment: "Provisionally", "tentatively", "potentially"

Comment: In other words, you're looking for appropriate weasel words?

Comment: Lol, a weasel word?

Omg I just looked it up, that's amazing! Whoever coined that term is awesome. Also yes, I am looking for a weasel word. Also cool name.

Comment: A tentative yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Yes but without obligation'. *

Answer (score 2):

"I'll pencil it in"

The implication being that it could be easily erased from your calendar.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people use 'tentatively'.

Answer (score 1):

***A firm maybe***  See the [Chicago Tribune](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/1989-04-09/travel/8904030202_1_general-theory-quantum-mechanics-physicists) for use of *firm maybe*, although in a different sense from yours.

See also [Gifted Leaders](http://www.giftedleaders.com/a-definite-possibility-of-a-firm-maybe/)

> A definite possibility of a firm maybe...

Answer (score 1):

> I agree [on condition that](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/on-condition-that) the project is proved feasible/sound.

A sort of euphemism for "I'm not entirely convinced that this project is worth my time and effort"

Answer (score 0):

["I wish I could, but I don't want to."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n780KlqdEwE)

Answer (score 0):

**[aquiesce](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquiesce)** (intransitive verb) : to accept, comply, or submit tacitly or passively —often used with “in” or “to”

Basically, when one refuses to object or stop and permits something to proceed when given a clear choice to stop something and notice that if they don't say anything the person will go ahead?

But this word does suggest a commitment.

It is more than "ignored" or "pretended I didn't hear" etc or "objected but they did it against my will" - it suggests giving permission for something one didn't really agree with but did agree to permit.